# Hiding section slides in beamer but not in the headline

Tags: beamer, sectioning, slideshow

Is there a way to hide a section slide in beamer without removing it from the headline?

Comment: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set `\AtBeginSection{}` within a group around the section:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\begin{document}

{
\AtBeginSection{}
\section{section}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
Some text.
\end{frame}
}

\section{section}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
Some text.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```